# Remove unwanted horizontel blue lines from excel generated using epplus which are not gridlines

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, epplus

I am working on generating excel using epplus in `MVC5` which is almost completed but still i am getting a bug in creation of excel file. I am ***getting*** ***Horizontal blue lines in the generated excel***.

I have tried making show grid lines to false but it is not helping. Also i have tried to make excel top or bottom border none of those particular rows in which the blue horizontal lines is showing

```
workSheet.Cells[7, 3, 7, 10000].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.ThiworkSheet.Cells["A9:AMJ9"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin; workSheet.Cells["A11:AMJ11"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
workSheet.Cells["A3:AMJ3"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
workSheet.Cells["A14:AMJ14"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
workSheet.Cells["A49:AMJ49"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.None;
workSheet.View.ShowGridLines = false;
```

**Question**

How to remove these unnecessary horizontal blue  lines?

Comment: workSheet.Cells["A99:AMJ99"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
            workSheet.Cells["A99:AMJ99"].Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(Color.PaleGreen);

Comment: It solved my problem

Comment: I have set border of cells in above code and then provided it same colour as that of the background of my excel sheet.